# GWT Maven project made with WebAppCreator don't work in devmode

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dev-mode

I have created a GWT project with maven configuration on this way :

```
webAppCreator -out HelloWorldGWT -templates sample,maven,readme ua.vitvyaz.hellowordgwt.HelloWorldGWT
```

I tried to run project on devmode :

```
mvn gwt:devmode
```

But in the browser i got :

```
"HTTP ERROR 404 

Problem accessing /HelloWorldGWT.html.

Reason: Not Found"
```

I looked, the directory WEB-INF was empty.

What is wrong in `pom.xml`?

**pom.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ua.vitvyaz.hellowordgwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorldGWT</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ua.vitvyaz.hellowordgwt.HelloWorldGWT</name>

  <properties>

    <!-- Setting maven.compiler.source to something different to 1.8
         needs that you configure the sourceLevel in gwt-maven-plugin since
         GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8 (see gwt-maven-plugin block below) -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Don't let your Mac use a crazy non-standard encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0-rc1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" update them in DevMode -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>import-sources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>import-test-sources</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>ua.vitvyaz.hellowordgwt.HelloWorldGWT</moduleName>
          <moduleShortName>HelloWorldGWT</moduleShortName>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
          <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
          <!-- Compiler configuration -->
          <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <!-- DevMode configuration -->
          <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
          <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
          <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
          <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>HelloWorldGWT.html</startupUrl>
          </startupUrls>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Skip normal test execution, we use gwt:test instead -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the GWT Documentation [page](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools.html) you should run `mvn gwt:run` to bring up the new application in superDevMode.

**UPDATE**

You have to build your project prior running it. In other words try:

`mvn clean package gwt:devmode`

It should work now.

Comment: mvn gwt:run don't work:
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run' in plugin net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6 among available goals add-super-sources, add-test-super-sou
s, codeserver, compile, devmode, enforce-encoding, generate-module, generate-module-metadata, help, import-sources, import-test-sources, package-app
est -> [Help 1]

Comment: @VitVyaz Yes you are right, it seems they have an error in their site. I am looking at it and I will update my answer if I find a solution. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @VitVyaz I think I found it, please check my updated answer

Answer (score 5):

From the `README.txt` that webAppCreator generated:

```
-- Option D: Using Maven --

If you have generated your project with the option '-maven', you have a 'pom.xml'
file ready to use. Assuming you have Maven installed in your system, 'mvn' is 
in your path, and you have access to maven repositories, you should be able to run:

mvn clean         # delete temporary stuff
mvn test          # run all the tests (gwt and junit)
mvn gwt:devmode   # run development mode (needs "mvn package" to be run before)
mvn package       # generate a .war package ready to deploy

For more information about other available goals, read Maven and gwt-maven-plugin 
documentation (http://maven.apache.org, https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/)
```

so first run `mvn package`, then `mvn gwt:devmode`.

The website still documents GWT 2.7, not 2.8 (as of September 2016).

Comment: My understanding is that with an ant gwt setup, you edit the html/css etc directly in the war folder, so refreshing in the browser will reflect changes immediately. So while this might be the state of things, it doesn't feel quite satisfactory. I feel like there should be some way to set the jetty launcher up so it prioritizes the stuff in src/main/webapp/.

Comment: What if you have configuration in Maven to filter the files (replace `${…}` placeholders), exclude some of them, add new web resource directories, etc. If you change something in `src/main/webapp`, rerun `mvn war:exploded`.